# Are there known issues with the Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6 namespace in 64 bit processes?

Tags: .net, vb.net, 64-bit, vb6-migration

Using classes from the Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6 namespace in a .NET Framework 4+ project yields the following warning:

> Warning BC40000:
> *<Class name>* is obsolete: 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.* classes are obsolete and supported within 32 bit processes only. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=160862

The project uses the classes `LabelArray`, `TextBoxArray` and `PictureBoxArray` as well as the methods `Format`, `SetItemData` and `GetItemData` from the `Support` module.

I'm aware that these classes are remnants of the VB6->VB.NET conversion wizard available in ancient Visual Studio versions and should not be used for new development. I am also aware that "not supported" means that I'm on my own if anything breaks.

That having been said, I am trying to assess the risk of switching an old legacy library that still uses those classes from x86 to AnyCPU, so that it can be used in a 64 bit host application. According to some preliminary tests, everything just "seems to work".

Apart from not being officially supported, are there any **concrete known issues** with using classes from the Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6 namespace in a 64 bit process?

Comment: "Not supported" doesn't mean "won't work", it means "don't call us when you have a problem".  It was the runtime library for the upgrade wizard in VS2008.  Not a success, removed again in VS2010.  The trouble Microsoft doesn't want to hear about is the vb6 code that the wizard did not address, Declare statements in particular.

Comment: @HansPassant: That's what I thought. On the other hand, Declare statements should not affect the compatibility UI elements in the Conversion namespace. Basically, I just want to confirm whether it's (a) *"we didn't test this with 64 bit, so don't bother us if it doesn't"* or (b) *"we know our code is broken with 64 bit and does some nasty things, but we don't want to fix it"*.

Comment: @Heinzi Effectively both. Go ahead and try it, but expect problems, especially if you're dabbling with 64bit numbers.